# Is there a way to delete HERE volatile layers w/o having to nuke the entire catalog/permissions?

Tags: here-olp

I need to Upscale a volatile layer. But since it cannot be modified, I would need to "clone" it.

Is there a way to delete layers w/o having to nuke the entire catalog/permissions/etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HERE Open Location Platform added support to delete volatile layers as part of OLP 2.5 release. The release notes can be found here: https://developer.here.com/olp/documentation/release-notes/location_platform_data_processing_release_notes_olp/release_notes/2.5.0.html

Please note that only volatile, stream and index layers can be deleted. You can delete layers using web UI, OLP CLI and REST API.

OLP CLI documentation: https://developer.here.com/olp/documentation/open-location-platform-cli/user_guide/topics/data/layer-commands.html#catalog-layer-delete
REST API documentation: https://developer.here.com/olp/documentation/data-store/data_dev_guide/rest/delete-a-layer.html

Answer (score 1):

You can delete a volatile layer through the REST API. The OLP CLI and Portal UI currently do not support layer deletion.